# SQL many-to-many filter out items rather than include

Tags: sql, many-to-many

So I'm building an app where one element is searching of movies. The data is stored in a relational database.

One of the filter criteria is genre. Movies can have multiple genres so it's a many-to-many relation. Other than the usual example of tags the filter doesn't quite work the same way.

Assuming you have a documentary with the genres `documentary` and `sports`. If I am interested in documentaries but not in sports, I very likely am not interested in sports related documentaries. If I implement the query like it's usually done with tags the query looks like this:

```
select distinct(m.id) from movies m
  join genres_movies gm.movie_id = m.id
  join genres on gm.genre_id = g.id
  where genre.name in ('documentary', 'action', 'horror')
```

With this query I would get the mentioned sports documentary. So how do I exclude all movies that have a certain genre?

Answer (score 0):

I think the exists and "not exists" are what you need

```
select distinct(m.id) from movies m
 where exists (select 1 
                 from genres g 
                 join genres_movies gm 
                   on gm.genre_id = g.id
                where gm.movie_id = m.id
                  and name in ('documentary', 'action', 'horror'))
   and not exists (select 1 
                     from genres g 
                     join genres_movies gm  
                       on gm.genre_id = g.id
                    where gm.movie_id = m.id
                      and g.name not in ('sports', 'drama'))
```

Comment: Not sure that would work. It would still return that one line that has the movie joined to the genre documentary

Comment: @leifg I've updated the answer. The previous version was a mess

Answer (score 0):

I like to use aggregation for this type of problem:

```
select gm.movie_id
from genres_movies gm join
     genres g
     on gm.genre_id = g.id
group by gm.movie_id
having sum(case when g.name in ('documentary', 'action', 'horror') then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when g.name = 'sports' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The `> 0` means that at least one of those genres is assigned.  The `= 0` means that none of those genres are assigned.

Because your code only selects the movie id, I removed the join to `movies`.  Of course, if you need other columns from that table, then put it back int.